# Create popups continuously in a loop without blocking the code

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, ctypes

My program streams data and I want to create a popup displaying some text whenever a condition is met. I tried to create a simple tkinter window and ctypes window, but both seem to block my code, preventing it from continuing until the window has been closed. How can I create simple popup window functionality in for example a loop?

What I have so far is something of this structure.

```py
import tkinter as tk
for i in range(11):
    if i%5 == 0:  # Any condition
        popup = tk.Tk()
        label = ttk.Label(popup, text='hi', font=('Verdana', 12))
        label.pack(side='top', padx=10, pady=10)
        popup.mainloop()
```

and

```py
import ctypes
for i in range(11):
    if i%5 == 0:  # Any condition
        popup = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
        popup(None, 'hi', 'title', 0)
```

However, in both cases the loop will not proceed until I close the popup.

Comment: Does your program otherwise have a Tkinter (or other) GUI being displayed?  In other words, is there a `.mainloop()` or equivalent already running?  That would make this a lot easier if true.

Comment: The program has no other GUI. I just wanted it to create popups when it finds some event (condition being met).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Case 1 - Tkinter:

You are using [`mainloop()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop) which is no different than a true while loop. You can make it run continuously by removing it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

for i in range(11):
    if i%5 == 0:  # Any condition
        popup = tk.Tk()
        label = ttk.Label(popup, text='hi', font=('Verdana', 12))
        label.pack(side='top', padx=10, pady=10)
```

### Case 2 - Ctypes:

To make it run continuously, you will have to use [`threading`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Threading).

```
import ctypes, threading

for i in range(11):
    if i%5 == 0:  # Any condition
        popup = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
        threading.Thread(target = lambda :popup(None, 'hi', 'title', 0)).start()
```

Comment: ctypes solution worked perfectly. I tried the tkinter solution and my loop was not blocked, but no popups appeared either. I thought it might be that the code finishes and automatically closes the popups so i added time.sleep(1) for each iteration, but I still did not see any popups.

Comment: @jerry tkinter solution works perfectly for me. I don't find any reason for it not to work. Does it show any error? Which OS are you using? Did you try the exact code I shared? I think the case is that you combined the code by *Krrr* with mine. *Krrr* included the command `root.withdraw` which hides the tkinter window

Comment: Im on Win10, and yea i created a new python file with only your code and ran it using anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Not too familiar with `ctypes`, but for `tkinter` the UI will always be blocking your main code during the `mainloop`.

You can somewhat bypass it if you just instantiate your `Tk()` without invoking `mainloop` and use the `after` function:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

for i in range(10):
    if i in (5, 8):
        root.after(ms=1, func=lambda x=i: showinfo('Message!', f'Stopped at {x}'))

# ... do something here
```

The `root.after` queues the message box to be displayed after 1 millisecond (`ms=1`).

A better way might be to create a modeless message/dialog box in `ctypes` but as mentioned, I'm not too familiar and a quick search didn't yield any simple solution.

Comment: I tried the code and my loop was not blocked, but no popups appeared either. I thought it might be that the code finishes and automatically closes the popups so i added time.sleep(1) for each iteration, but I still did not see any popups.

Comment: Odd, it showed up for me on my IDE and running in console/consoleless as well.  Granted, I did use `time.sleep(3)` just to make sure.